# How to exclude tables/children from result in RedBeanPHP

Tags: php, sql, redbean

I have modelled a relation like this is RedBeanPHP:

```
Car
id    color    ownPart

Part
id    name
```

So RedBean creates the SQL tables as expected:

```
Car
id    color

Part
id    name    car_id
```

This works great.

However, I have other tables in my DB, e.g. a `User` that also has a `car_id` identifying the users car.

When I want to query all `Car`s and its children (`Part`s) by

```
$cars = R::find('car');
$foo = R::exportAll( $cars ); echo json_encode($foo);
```

the JSON also contains every `User` related to a car.

How can I query just the cars with their "real" children?

Answer (score 1):

[`exportAll`](https://github.com/gabordemooij/redbean/blob/a09f649ac809b05cfd122e061a9602d3fa2a2108/RedBeanPHP/DuplicationManager.php) specifies a third parameter `$filter` that you should be able to use to specify which relationships are also exported:

```
$foo = R::exportAll($cars, false, array('part'));
```

Comment: Thanks! This is great! Just one following problem: How to use this for the nested arrays? E.g. my `part`s have `srew`s (=> a `screw` has a `part_id`) and there are `brokenpart`s in the DB that also have a `part_id`. But I just want to display the parts `screw`s in the JSON.

Comment: @A2i_ You'll need to do this outside of RedBean. I don't believe it supports more complex filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Please read Jacobs Answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27253767/2707529) if you have the problem at just on level (see my comment below his answer).

I had multidimensional arrays to filter, so after hours of trying I finally got at least a workaround by not filtering what I want but deleting what I do not want:

```
$cars = R::find('car');
$foo = R::exportAll( $cars );

$keystoremove = array("ownPart", "ownBrokenpart");
delFromArray($foo, $keystoremove );

echo json_encode($foo);


function delFromArray(&$array, $keys) { 
  foreach ($array as $key => &$value) { 
      if (in_array($key, $keys, true)){
        unset($array[$key]);
      }
      else {
        if (is_array($value)) { 
            delFromArray($value, $keys); 
        }
      }

  }
}
```